# Port forwarding issues for MC server, WAN IP gets ports forwarded , but LAN IP for the home server does not

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, minecraft, cable-modem

**- Router- TP link ac4000 Archer A20 ver 3.6**

**- Modem Hitron model EN2251**

*I can get a new modem and router if needed*

I'm just trying to make a home server , that can also host a Minecraft server for the house and friends outside of the network.
the server works no issues locally , but when I try to forward ports for outside connections I have so many issues.

1. DHCP is enabled , it has a static IP on the home server.
2. (port forwarding enabled ([virtual server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42qnM.png)) on router to the home server.
3. ports are listed to get through the windows firewall.
4. enabling **DMZ** did not get my ports open.
5. I called my ISP I do not have double Nat , I have a dynamic public
   IP
6. called TP link they did everything I did , and then said I have to
   contact the manufacturer of my home server ( its just spare computer
   parts from old machines)
7. I've tried software(**Port Forward network utilities**, and **Port forwarding wizard**) , I get errors on the **TCP** side but not the **UDP**
   side
8. my current IP for my Internet (**WAN**) has Forwarded Ports when the server is
   running, but not the machine where it is hosted.
9. I've turned off the firewall for the PC and the Router, even
   disabling my pi hole (I'm desperate, its been days. Only 4 I'm very
   much over reacting).
10. I have called my ISP multiple times, my modem is bridged, I have a
    public IP, I do not have Double Nat.
11. I've tried **port triggering**
12. My ISP Does not Block port 25565
13. changing the port from 25565 to 25566 created the same results
    changing nothing.

Please I need help , I'll do anything at this point, I just wanna play some Minecraft with the boys.
again I can get a new modem or router if needed.

Comment: what actual issues do you have? is it just being unable to connect, or something more than that? does the _router_ have a public IP? what "software" and what "errors" are you referring to in #7? is this a Java or Bedrock server?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the NAT settings on your router?

Comment: I added a picture and linked it in (virtual servers) i hope that's what you were referring too I'm still new to all of this

Comment: for more clarification , the server runs fine locally no issues , but people outside my network trying to join cant join because i cant seem to get port forwarding to work.

Comment: What are the first two digit groups (e.g. 192.168) of your public IP address as reported by the router's web interface? Is this the same IP address you get when you visit a "what's my IP" service?

Comment: public IP is 97.99.xxx.xxx yes they are the same

Comment: `my current IP for my Internet (WAN) has Forwarded Ports when the server is running, but not the machine where it is hosted.` What exactly do you mean by this? Also the title of your question is confusing. Were you just trying to say like you set up port forwarding but it does not work?